# How can I sum the result of number values?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, sum

Hi im a beginner in Python. and I've just a simple question for you but I can't figure it out anyway.

```
for i in range(7,10):
    function= (1/i)
    i+=1
    print(function)
```

then it prints

```
0.14285714285714285
0.125
0.1111111111111111
```

but firstly I want to sum these values and after that print.
How can i?

Comment: What is `function` ? Is that a function?

Comment: @howaboutNO its just a variable such as `i , x `

Comment: what would be the exact value of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is almost like natural language:

```
print(sum(1 / i for i in range(7, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
total = 0

for i in range(7,10):
    function = 1/i
    total = total + function

print(total)
```

The idea is that every time the iteration is ran i increases by one, also since the range is a list (`[7,8,9,10]`), the first time `i` will be 7, then 8 and so on. The only printed value will be the total sumation at the end. Hope this helps.